# Slick carousel not allowing image to scale properly

Tags: html, css, slick.js

I'm using slick to make an image carousel. I've got it working but I want to be able to have the center image scale and be bigger than the others. I have it kinda working but the height of the container does not change when the image scales meaning the image flows outside the container and doesn't scale in height properly. I want it to work like it does here on the demo for center mode http://kenwheeler.github.io/slick/

How can I get the height to change when the image is scaled?

Comment: can you provide your html, css and jquery code for the slider only. It will help if you can provide a working codepen demo.

Comment: Ok I'll give it a go, thanks

Comment: had to put the demo here as I can't fit all the code due to not having enough characters demo: https://codepen.io/Reece_Dev/pen/OgZGvJ

Comment: I have provided my answer below. Please click on tick if this solves your question so it can be closed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you carefully see their demo and increase the scale size, then you can see that even in their demo the white box will get cropped.

The solution is to give a margin to the slides so the central image has place to be seen. Following code will help you achieve what you want:

```
.slick-slide {
    margin: 50px 0;
}
```

All I have done is, added margin top and bottom. The end result is that there is white space above and below the slides that are not active, but the empty space is covered by the scaled image in the center slide.

Working CodePen:
https://codepen.io/vikrant-icd/pen/vZjMPq